# A question related to newton Binomial Theorem I am unable to think about

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

I am trying to solve assignment of an Institute in which I don't study and I am unable to get answer of this question. For theory, I am studying Introductory Combinatorics by Richard Brualdi.

> Question is -> Show that $  (1-4x)^{-1/2} $ generates the sequence $ {2n \choose n} $ .
>
> Using Newton Binomial formula I am getting $\frac{ (2n) (2n-2) ... (2n-2k +2)  2^k } { k! } $  which will not yield the answer.

I don't know where I am mistaken . Can someone please give a detained answer. I cannot ask anyone as I am self studying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You obtained something with two variables: $n$ and $k$. The required coefficient depends on $n$ only!

Using the [(generalized) binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem) means that
$$(1-4x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}{n}(-4)^{n} x^n.$$
Now expand the binomial coefficient
$$\begin{align}
\binom{-1/2}{n}(-4)^{n}&=\frac{(-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{3}{2})(-\frac{5}{2})\dots (-\frac{1}{2}-n+1)(-4)^{n}}{n!}\\
&=\frac{(1)(3)(5)\dots (2n-1)(2)^{n}}{n!}
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?